# Parallel Backpressure on Downstream Process Completion

Tags: java, project-reactor

using Project Reactor and Java 8 (I know...) I would like to implement the following:

I have a supplier (0..n) that produces `String`s (directory paths to run a process on). The supplier function is:

```java
public Optional<String> nextPath();
```

I have a consumer (a process run on the directory) that looks like:

```java
void process(String directoryPath);
```

It's dummy implementation might look like this:

```java
void process(String directoryPath) {
    // process runs in a different Thread started by an application server
    // I don't have access to changing this
    new Thread(() -> {
        Thread.sleep(randomTimeToComplete);
        // complete
    })
    .start();
}
```

I need to be able to **concurrently run up to 4 of those processes at a time**.

1. This means that I start the app with 0 processes running.
2. An event triggers the flow, 4 directory paths are requested initially.
3. After each process completes a new `directoryPath` is requested to start a new process at the spot of the finished one.

I am not sure how to go about this *signaling* at the end of the process.

My naïve implementation looks like this:

```java
Flux.<String>generate(sink -> {
    Optional<String> = possiblyNextPath = pathService.nextPath();
    if (possiblyNextPath.isPresent()) {
        sink.next(possiblyNextPath.get());
    } else {
        sink.complete();
    }
})
// here I'm using a future, I can eventually make the process
// signal completion via a CompletableFuture
// but I don't think this is the 'reactor' way
.flatMap(path -> Mono.fromFuture(startProcess(path)), 4) // 4 is max processes at a time
.subscribe();
```

```java
public CompletableFuture<Object> startProcess(String path) {
    CompletableFuture<Object> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

    new Thread(() -> {
        // Thread.sleep(15_000);
        future.complete(null);
    })
    .start();

    return future;
}
```

Is there a way to better implement backpressure with my requirements of having 4 processes running at a time, one after each completes.

I am thinking about something to signal completion, but using a semaphore or any other Java concurrency technique seems to be either blocking or not something I've seen in code snippets about reactor.